# Modeling data in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to come up with a good model for (what I would consider) a somewhat complicated class. There are two entities which are independent of each other (in that they have use, by themselves, elsewhere in the app), a User Group and an Event Type.

A User Group has a list of event types to which they are entitled. And beyond that, there is a list of strings which applies to each combination of User Group and Event which tells the app strings to replace later on (so a Dictionary where they key is a field to replace and the value is the value to replace it with).

I come from more of a SQL background, so it's easy for me to think in terms of tables and primary keys. This structure would be keyed off `UserGroupID, EventTypeID, NameToReplace`, but when I try to come up with a way to do it in C#, I end up with ugly (or at least I think they're ugly) structures like `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<tuple<int, string>, string>>` or `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>>`

I could also do away with the dictionary concept and just make a list of tuples, or a list of custom classes which tie all the logical "keys" together.

My question(s) come down to, is this sort of nested collection structure common and/or a good idea? Are there best practices when modeling data like this anyone can point me to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what class structure you have thought of?

Comment: "list of custom classes which tie all the logical "keys" together" That would be the cleanest solution.  A little code up front to avoid having to mes with loosely-types dictionaries and tuples.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know if there's much/any performance hit if you have a dictionary keyed off of an object as opposed to something like an `int`? Or does it really come down to how you override `Equals()`?

Comment: Actually it depends on how you override `GetHashCode` since that's what's used to find the matching item in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

So, this might be controversial, but I wanted to put this version out for discussion, to know how appropriate this approach would be.

Assuming you don't have millions of groups and event types, you could pack those into kind of Composite Key in db terms with bits shift :

```
public static int Combine(int value1, int value2)
{
    return value1 | (value2 << 8);
}
```

Then `Dictionary<int, string>` would be work fine.

```
dictionary.Add(Combine(UserGroupID, EventTypeID), NameToReplace)
```

And to get the value :

```
dictionary[Combine(UserGroupID, EventTypeID)] // Or TryGetValue()
```